# Error using zef to install Twitter module

Tags: raku, zef

I'm using zef to install the Twitter module with `zef install Twitter`

I'm getting the following error:

`Enabled fetching backends [git path curl wget] don't understand git://github.com/raku-community-modules/Twitter You may need to configure one of the following backends, or install its underlying software - [pswebrequest]`

I've googled 'pswebrequest' and I'm not getting anything of note.

I've tried installing HTTP::Tinyish, one of the dependencies, to check that my zef installation is working properly, and that was fine.

Any pointers on how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `source-url` should end with `.git` if its a git repository, as the backends use extensions to figure out how/what is needed to fetch/extract various types of packaged distributions.

You could open a pull request to add the `.git` to the source-url, or you could work around it manually via:

`zef install https://github.com/raku-community-modules/Twitter.git`

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Will pop in a PR, but the manual way worked.